# Parse: Add user to role using cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Im using parse as a backend for the very first time. In my business the user has to choose between 2 roles at the register page: "Role1" and "Role2". If I understand the docs the access to "_Role" class should be read only, so the best way to add a user to a role while this user is trying to register is through cloud code.

My idea (not sure its the best practice) is to first add a column to this user, called "role" so the user object will look like this :

```
{
    username: "John Doe",
    email: "john@doe.com",
    role: "Role1",
    createdAt : ...
    ...
}
```

and second, add this user to the role "Role1" using cloud code.

Here is the cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
var user = request.user;
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
// user.role is undefined here !!!
query.equalTo("name", user.role);
query.first({ success: function(role) {
    role.relation("users").add(user);
    role.save();
} ,error: function(error){
    console.log('error');
    console.log(error); 
}});
```

});

As you can see in this code, i need to get the user role by its name using a query. the role is supposed to be stored in the user object, this is not the case in this code.

**Question :** how can I access the role field in the cloud code ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `role` field we must use `user.get('role')` and not `user.role`

Notice: if you are using the 1.6.0 sdk the code will fail, consider changing the value to 1.5.0 in your ".parse.project" file, waiting for this bug to be fixed.